# Reset my upload key on the new Play Store console

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, android-keystore

0

My app's keystore was lost, and I had to reset the key.
With the new PlayStore console, I'm lost.

I used to do it from `Setup > App integrity > App signing tab`

how do i do it with the console UI ?

Google play removed the option **request upload key reset**

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic